# ASP.NET Core 7 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I've built a Web API in ASP.NET Core 7. I have published it to one of our servers and have configured the API in IIS and set the firewall etc.

I'm trying to test the calls in Postman, the call takes ages to execute and then fails with an "internal server" error. I have other API's setup on this server that I wrote in earlier versions of ASP.NET and these work fine.

Is there special configurations or settings in .NET Core 7 that need to made in the app before publishing to get the API to work correctly? I know this is a broad question, but I can't seem to find a config guide.

Comment: Read up on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You don’t provide any code or error messages, and your question is more a discussion.

Comment: "_get the API to work correctly_" doesn't really make sense, as it can mean any one of a number of things. If it all works locally, but gives an error when deployed, then it's very likely to be something like a difference in the data between your local database and the deployed one. We just went through exactly the same thing with a deployed API. I'm not saying it isn't a config thing, but I would be inclined to add loads of logging to your code and see what that shows first. It's quite possible that you have an exception somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @AvrohomYisroel, it works perfectly locally and usually Postman would give some kind of error message. I'm not stuck with code in this question, it's more of a discussion as I thought that maybe new configurations were required in Core 7. I'll add in more error logs to see if I can isolate the issue, thank you for your suggestion.